# Total friend list count in Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

Documentation for FQL seems to be lacking on the official website, here is a query I tried:

```
  FB.api("/fql?q=SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = me()", function(response) {
            $("#fbfriends_count").text(response);
        });
```

My #fbfriends_count prints out an [object Object], so I researched for a bit and found what my  array looks like:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "friend_count": 152
    }
  ]
}
```

So now I tried:

```
 $("#fbfriends_count").text(response["data"]["friend_count"]);
```

But this returns me nothing, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"data" is an array, use `response["data"][0]["friend_count"]` or `response.data[0].friends_count`